# Asset Precompile issue in RoR - Duplicate Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rvm 2.2.1 version and trying to compile my assets locally and it is working properly.

Whenever I'm modifying something in app/assets, it is adding duplicate assets in my public/assets folder. I'm running the following commands to rebuild my codebase.

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production assets:clean
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production assets:precompile
```

Sample duplicate assets:

```
[webauto@web-ci-slave4-alpha shop]$ ls -lrt /var/lib/jenkins/test/shop/public/assets/hello-*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webauto webauto  41 Sep  7 11:00 /var/lib/jenkins/test/shop/public/assets/hello-3781f94ea812bb33437de9049e04bc3af41a0e7397164b057379c08c3b0ac489.js.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webauto webauto  21 Sep  7 11:00 /var/lib/jenkins/test/shop/public/assets/hello-3781f94ea812bb33437de9049e04bc3af41a0e7397164b057379c08c3b0ac489.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webauto webauto  54 Sep  7 11:05 /var/lib/jenkins/test/shop/public/assets/hello-c63e283c3fa4c225fee1e8efcc76ef9ff7ad217eac34344beb0441a946f13534.js.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webauto webauto  87 Sep  7 11:05 /var/lib/jenkins/test/shop/public/assets/hello-c63e283c3fa4c225fee1e8efcc76ef9ff7ad217eac34344beb0441a946f13534.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webauto webauto  54 Sep  7 11:18 /var/lib/jenkins/test/shop/public/assets/hello-f55b89d4c36cfe653707589edc83607130db7014e1d8d4a4f9c9074b1dce224b.js.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webauto webauto 131 Sep  7 11:18 /var/lib/jenkins/test/shop/public/assets/hello-f55b89d4c36cfe653707589edc83607130db7014e1d8d4a4f9c9074b1dce224b.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webauto webauto  54 Sep  7 11:39 /var/lib/jenkins/test/shop/public/assets/hello-bd8851907bef1e34c111190348f2c1945a04e96c3e5a6c5a252394794af093c5.js.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webauto webauto 153 Sep  7 11:39 /var/lib/jenkins/test/shop/public/assets/hello-bd8851907bef1e34c111190348f2c1945a04e96c3e5a6c5a252394794af093c5.js
[webauto@web-ci-slave4-alpha shop]$
```

I am expecting to update the existing asset(s), not to add the new one which will grow my public folder with duplicate asset entries. Could anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vennila K

Comment: can you please try with `assets:clobber` instead of `clean` and then `assets:precompile` and then check if it is generating duplicate ?

Comment: assets:clobber will delete the whole public/asset folder and precompile will do the compilation for whole asset and it will take time to complete.

I just want to compile the updated assets alone instead all.

Thanks!!

Comment: try rake assets:precompile

Comment: `rake assets:clean` leaves the 3 most recent versions. So what you are seeing is I think correct and intentional. It allows rolling updates.

Comment: It's growing whenever we update the assets not 3 or 4. Is it maintains for rolling back, is it configurable anywhere?

Comment: The 'keep' value is set to 2 by default in https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb, so that should mean having a total of 3 versions after `clean`. So I guess that that value is being changed by something, see here: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md#customize

Comment: Thanks @brod. Yes correct. We can run the `clean` after `precompile` to remove the old assets.

Even I changed the values ( count & age ) in manifest.rb, but its not taking effect. Should I do anything else to make it work.

I changed `def clean(count = 2, age = 3600)` to `def clean(count = 1, age = 0)` and saved the file then run the clean command.

its keeping 2 backups and 1 new asset, so totally 3 files now.